# Why this header code takes references chapter(numberless) as chapter number 4 in header instead of only word Refrences

Tags: footer, header

```
\usepackage{lastpage} % number of last page 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\fancyhead[R]{\color{myblue}
   \rmfamily \bfseries
   \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi
   \leftmark}

\renewcommand\footrule{\color{myblue}\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize height 2pt \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize   
\end{minipage}\par}%

\renewcommand\headrule{\color{myblue}
\begin{minipage}{1\textwidth}
\hrule width \hsize \kern 1mm \hrule width \hsize height 2pt 
\end{minipage}}%
\lhead{}

\lfoot{}
\rfoot{Page \thepage\ of \pageref{LastPage}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunaly there is no MWE in the question and I do not know how the title of the unnumbered chapter goes to the header. So its only a guess: add the chapter name and chapter number to the left mark in the `\chaptermark` command. Maybe you have to use `\nouppercase` for `\leftmark`, too.

```latex
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{%
  \markboth{%
    \ifnum\value{chapter}>0 \chaptername\ \thechapter. \fi% <-added (and removed in \fancyhead[R])
  #1}{}}
\fancyhead[R]{\color{myblue}%
   \rmfamily \bfseries
   \nouppercase{\leftmark}% <- \nouppercase added
}
```

Comment: Respect Sir. U are 100% correct as per my requirements. U nailed it and u beauty.Thank u very much for your cooperation.Best wishes for U and be blessed!